# How to make custom navigation bar

Tags: flutter, navigation, flutter-animation

Hi you can help me to achieve this custom navigation bar. I am using this type of navigation first time in my app. So, please guide me in it

[image]

I have tried it by using the making custom panel and path. But is not working so u can help me in this.

Comment: can you include that you;ve tried so far

Comment: yes, I have tried it by using the custom paint after that I have make one more class for giving the path and color of it. but it is not working through that also

Comment: you can search for notchedShapeBottomNav

Comment: same nav design. https://github.com/jbjason/complex_ui/blob/main/lib/screens/travel_ui/trav_widgets/trav_home/trav_nav_bar.dart

Comment: If you want to do it in a very simple way then use svg image of the blue background and then put your icons manually over that.

Comment: If you are willing to use a package, Then use [this](https://pub.dev/packages/fluid_bottom_nav_bar) package.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `bottomNavigationBar` with `BottomAppBar` which has *shape* property:

```
floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
  onPressed: () {},
  child: const Icon(Icons.home_filled),
),
bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
  color: Colors.yellow[100],
  shape: const CircularNotchedRectangle(),
  child: Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
    children: [
      IconButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        icon: const Icon(Icons.shopping_bag),
      ),
      IconButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        icon: const Icon(Icons.money),
      ),
      IconButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        icon: const Icon(Icons.currency_bitcoin),
      ),
      IconButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        icon: const Icon(Icons.bar_chart),
      ),
    ],
  ),
),
```

> set shape property as `CircularNotchedRectangle()`

[image]

This should be the final code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Flutter Navigation Bar')),
        body: Center(
          child: Text(
            'Hello, world!',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
          ),
        ),
        bottomNavigationBar: FluidNavBar(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class FluidNavBar extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FluidNavBarState createState() => _FluidNavBarState();
}

class _FluidNavBarState extends State<FluidNavBar> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;

  List<NavItem> _navItems = [
    NavItem(Icons.shopping_bag, "Shop"),
    NavItem(Icons.money, "Money"),
    NavItem(Icons.currency_bitcoin, "Bitcoin"),
    NavItem(Icons.bar_chart, "Chart"),
  ];

  void _onNavItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        child: const Icon(Icons.home_filled),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
        color: Colors.yellow[100],
        shape: const CircularNotchedRectangle(),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: _navItems.map((item) {
            var index = _navItems.indexOf(item);
            return IconButton(
              onPressed: () => _onNavItemTapped(index),
              icon: Icon(
                item.icon,
                color: _selectedIndex == index ? Colors.yellow : Colors.grey,
              ),
            );
          }).toList(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class NavItem {
  IconData icon;
  String title;

  NavItem(this.icon, this.title);
}
```